# Normal modes from equations of motion

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, classical-mechanics

Normal modes of oscillation for a double pendulum are motions of the pendulum in which the coordinates $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ vary harmonically in time with the same frequency and phase, but not necessarily with the same amplitude.

Once we have linearised equations of motion, it is said that one can substitute in harmonic solutions to identify the two normal mode frequencies.  What does this mean in the example below

$\tau_1 = (I + md^2) \ddot{\phi}_1 + I \ddot{\phi}_2, $

$\tau_2 = I \ddot{\phi}_2.$

What are the harmonic solutions and how do they lead to two normal frequencies if  we assume $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$ to be the same, for example?

The form of these equations is the usual one in mechanics of

$
 \boldsymbol{\tau} = \textbf{A} \ddot{\boldsymbol{\phi}}  + \textbf{b} .$

This can be rewritten as

$\ddot{\boldsymbol{\phi}} = \textbf{f} ( \boldsymbol{\phi}, \dot{\boldsymbol{\phi}}, \boldsymbol{\tau} )$

Comment: In a normal mode $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ oscillate with the same frequency (by definition), so let $\phi_1=C_1e^{i\omega t}$ and $\phi_2=C_2e^{i\omega t}$. Note same frequency $\omega$. Substitute these into the equations of motion and solve for $\omega$

Comment: If you put that into the above equations, don't you add up with a factor of $e^{i \omega t}$ somewhere, how can this be removed to solve for $\omega$?

Comment: Ah! With the $\tau$ on the left, you have some inhomogenous equations. For SHM and **constant** inhomogenous terms, the frequency of the homogenous and inhomogenous solutions is the same (which you can check!). So you may write a new set of equations without the $\tau$ and work with those instead. 
Wait a moment! Are the $\tau$ meant to be *torques*!?

Comment: Yes, the two $\tau$'s are both torques ie. you have equations of motion for the two torques about the joints for the two bodies in a double pendulum.

Comment: If they're torques then they are definitely *not constants*! You first need to express the torques in terms of the $\phi$ and then apply my comment 1

Comment: I made an edit above, is this what you meant?  Once it's rewritten in this form it's usual to solve numerically or in this case plug in the harmonic solutions and solve for $\omega$.

Comment: It's not quite what I meant. Sorry, perhaps my comments were confusing too. The differential equations are only fully defined once you specify $\tau(\phi,\phi', ...)$. Presumably this may be done using Newton's law, or (simpler) if you know Lagrangian mechanics, use that to find the equations of motion without worrying about torques. Eventually, your equations of motion should look [like 17.5.5 and 17.5.6 here](https://phys.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Classical_Mechanics/Classical_Mechanics_(Tatum)/17%3A_Vibrating_Systems/17.05%3A_Double_Pendulum)

Comment: [continued] Then, once you have the equations of motion written in terms of the $\phi$ (and derivatives) you may substitute the harmonic solutions and solve for $\omega$

Comment: I have seen elsewhere in robotics people will often write down the torques using Newton's law o obtain something like $
 \boldsymbol{\tau} = \textbf{A} \ddot{\boldsymbol{\phi}}  + \textbf{b} $ and then suggest solving it numerically for the angular speeds and positions of the pendulums, does this mean that one has to assume that the torques are known?

Comment: So for example above $
 \boldsymbol{\tau} = \textbf{A} \ddot{\boldsymbol{\phi}}  + \textbf{b} $ would be considered two equations for two unknowns $\ddot{\phi}_1$ and $\ddot{\phi}_2$, but how are these solved numerically if $\tau$ depends on $\phi, \phi', ...$?

Comment: The equation $\tau =A\ddot{\phi}+b$ cannot be solved (numerically or otherwise) until you specify what $\tau$, $A$, and $b$ are. Specifying these amounts to fully defining the system you are studying. Look at the simple pendulum first before the generalizations. See how to get to this equation and see how to solve it